# Using Channel Form to populate VMG Chosen Member Field with member_id

Tags: safecracker, vmg-chosen-member

Can't seem to figure out how to add members via Channel Form to a VMG Chosen Member field.

Members need to be able to sign up for a session of their choosing on the front-end and be associated with that particular session in the CP.

There isn't any documentation on the vmg_chosen_member git page other than how to format/style the field if you're using {field:session-attendees}.

Ideally, I would pass the logged in member_id via a text input field like so:

```
{exp:channel:form channel="sessions" entry_id="{last_segment}" id="session-registration" class="session-form" return="url/success"}

<input name="session-attendees" type="text" value="{member_id}" />

<input type="submit" value="Register for this session" />

{/exp:channel:form}
```

But that doesn't work.

I don't want to use {field:session-attendees} because the member signing up for a session does not need to see the other members signed up.

What's the proper way to add members to a chosen member field via Channel Form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting to pass in a member_id to a VMG Chosen Member field, you'll need to pass it in as an array with a single member_id. The following should work for you, but let me know if you still have issues!

```
{exp:channel:form channel="sessions" entry_id="{last_segment}" id="session-registration" class="session-form" return="url/success"}

<input name="field_id_1[]" type="text" value="{member_id}" />

<input type="submit" value="Register for this session" />

{/exp:channel:form}
```

(replace `field_id_1[]` with the ID of your VMG Chosen Member field)

Comment: Thank you!

I didn't include this in the original question, but I also needed to maintain the previous users who were registered for the session, and implementing your method (which worked) removed the previous registrants.

To get around this, I added additional hidden fields with the previous member_ids to the form (input via stash variable), so when a new member signs up, it's like they're all signing up again.

There's probably a more efficient way to do this, but it works as there is a limit of 6 registrants per session.

Thanks, again.